# Compound daily interest with monthly deposits over x amount of years in excel

Tags: calculation, deposits, compound-interest, spreadsheet

This is **compound interest calculated daily** and topped up with  deposits every month e.g Begin with $100, earn 2% interest earned  daily even on weekends, and then come month end invest another $100 on the compounded amount.

Please assist in how I can achieve this in Excel and what the formula is.

Comment: Welcome to PF&M. We prefer questions that show research effort. How far have you got on your own?

Comment: I have interest that is calculated daily on a spread sheet where i can change the principal and the interest rate but i don't know how to add the monthly deposit amount into the formula. **($D$2*(1+$E$2)^A2)*** Where column D is my Principal and column E is the interest rate. That formula is on column B

Comment: Would it be simpler to have 12 separate cells?

Comment: If that is the easier option so be it will be fine by me

Comment: How does your formula for the month account for daily rounding?

Answer (score 2):

The future value function in Excel is detailed here: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-fv-function

Assuming the nominal interest rate is 2% per annum compounded monthly.

Future value after depositing $100 each month for 12 months.

```
=FV(rate, nper, pmt, [pv], [type])

=FV(0.02/12,12,-100,0,1)
```

> $1,213.08

This is the calculation the Excel function is doing.

```
With

n = 12
d = 100
r = 0.02/12

fv = d (1 + r)^1 + d (1 + r)^2 + ... + d (1 + r)^11 + d (1 + r)^12 = 1213.08
```

This can be converted to a formula.

[image]

which is equivalent to the one here: http://financeformulas.net/Future-Value-of-Annuity-Due.html

***Daily Interest***

The phrase "calculated daily" means mid-month cash flows have the partial month interest accumulated correctly.  However, the $100 cash flows in the question are monthly so mid-period cash flows are not relevant and the above method can be used, (albeit with equal length months).

Nevertheless a daily calculation can be made.

The following assumes the nominal interest rate is 2% per annum compounded daily.  This is not quite the same as 2% per annum compounded monthly - [ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation), (but the difference to the result amounts only to 1 cent.)

*Screenshot showing Excel formulas*

[image]

It is unlikely you would require daily interest to be calculated on calendar months i.e. with unequal number of days per month.  However, if you *did* require it there is no short Excel formula for it.

Answer (score 1):

I put the start date in A2, then A3 is

> A2 + 1

Starting balance is in D2 and daily interest in E2 as you have it.

D3 is then

> =D2+ROUND(D2*E$2,2)+IF(MONTH(A4)<>MONTH(A3),100,0)

That is the previous balance (D2), plus the days interest (D2*E$2), plus, if tomorrow is a different month than today (i.e. today is the last day of the month) $100.

Copy your row 365 times and you get your answer for the year.